# Cannot use chrome cast button with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-cast

I am trying to use Selenium to cast youtube videos to my chromecast. When I open youtube in chrome normally I see the cast button and it works fine. When I open it with Selenium the cast button is missing, and when I select Cast from menu it gives me the error "No Cast destinations found. Need help?"

I am using python, and have tried lots of combinations of flags with webdriver. Here is what I have

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=./ChromeProfile')
options.add_argument('--disable-session-crashed-bubble')
options.add_argument('--disable-save-password-bubble')
options.add_argument('--disable-permissions-bubbles')
options.add_argument('--bwsi')
options.add_argument('--load-media-router-component-extension')
options.add_argument('--enable-video-player-chromecast-support');

excludeList = ['disable-component-update',
  'ignore-certificate-errors',
]
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', excludeList)

chromedriverPath = '/my/path/to/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriverPath, chrome_options=options)

path = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bz9Lza059NU'
driver.get(path);
time.sleep(60) # Let the user actually see something!
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Can you provide us a snapshot of the `cast button` to understand where it is exactly located? Thanks

Comment: By cast button, I mean the icon used to cast to the chromecast, it is at the bottom of the youtube video next to the full screen icon, and looks like this http://images.anandtech.com/doci/7186/Screen%20Shot%202013-07-28%20at%207.48.34%20PM.png

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to get it working. It seemed to require two steps. Copying my default profile over to somewhere selenium could use it, and figuring out the correct flags to use when opening chrome. The key being selenium automatically added a bunch of flags that I didn't want, so I had to exclude one.

First to find out where my profile is stored, I opened up chrome to this url `chrome://version/`.

This gave me lots of information, but the important ones were

> **Command Line:** /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser --enable-pinch --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end
>
> **Profile Path:** /home/mdorrell/.config/chromium/Default

First I copied my profile to some directory that Selenium could use

```
cp -R /home/mdorrell/.config/chromium/Default/* /home/mdorrell/ChromeProfile
```

Then I opened this same page in the browser opened by selenium and got the list of flags that selenium added from the `Command Line` row. The one that ended up giving me the problems was `--disable-default-apps`

In the end the code that I needed to add ended up looking like this

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

# Set the user data directory
options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=/home/mdorrell/ChromeProfile')

# get list of flags selenium adds that we want to exclude
excludeList = [
  'disable-default-apps',
]
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', excludeList)

chromedriverPath = '/my/path/to/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriverPath, chrome_options=options)

path = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bz9Lza059NU'
driver.get(path);
time.sleep(60) # Let the user actually see something!
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Is adding the user data directory necessary ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @MikeD for sharing your answer.

I was having the same issue when I wanted to chrome cast a R Shiny Dashboard via a selenium browser (with RSelenium). If I'd click on `Cast` it would show me "*No Cast destinations found. Need help?*", whereas from a normal browser it works fine.

In my case, it worked after excluding two switches (including the ChromeProfile was not necessary), which in R can be done with:

```
library(RSelenium)

options <- list()
options$chromeOptions$excludeSwitches <- list('disable-background-networking',
                                              'disable-default-apps')

rD <- rsDriver(verbose = FALSE, port = 4570L, extraCapabilities = options)
```